# Logout - Taleo User

Tags: taleo

I'm accessing the taleo api. I'm able to open the connection with the hosturl, username and password. But when I try to close or logout the session am unable to do it.

I have opened up the 20 connections now.

How to reset all those connections now?

Logout Request :

POST https://abc.tbe.taleo.net/xxxxx/ats/api/v1/logout

Logout response :

```
{
 "response": {},
 "status": {
 "success": false,
 "detail": {
 "errormessage": "Login session for token null is expired or invaid.",
 "error": "Login session for token null is expired or invalid.",
 "operation": "internal",
 "errorcode": "500"
  }
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. We need to add the authorization token as the cookie like follows .

add in the Header :

```
Cookie authToken="authorization_token"
```

Note: authorization_token between quotes